# sed not parsing \t as a tab

Tags: sed

I am trying to insert a line into a coffee script using sed and it looks as if it is ignoring my first tab character.

The file I want to insert into has a line like this:

```
    karmaServer.start
```

and I want to insert a line after it like this:

```
    karmaServer.start
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
```

So I wrote a sed script that I think should work

```
sed "/^\t\tkarmaServer.start/a\t\t\t\tflags: ['--no-sandbox']" build/unit-test.coffee
```

although the result is quite odd. I get the following

```
    karmaServer.start
t       flags: ['--no-sandbox']
```

And I don't understand why it starts the line with a `t` character or how to get rid of it.

any ideas?

Comment: This is not the behaviour of  all `sed`s, note.  Spinellis `sed` says "extra characters after `\ ` at the end of `a` command" and fails.

Answer (score 2):

You must add a newline in your `sed` command (and then account for the shell's handling of escaped newlines):

```
 sed "/^\t\tkarmaServer.start/a\\
 \t\t\t\tflags: ['--no-sandbox']" build/unit-test.coffee
```

As the GNU `sed` manual says:

> a \
>
> text Append text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a backslash.

This is not very clear, unformatted like this.  (It isn't particularly clearer when viewed with the `man` command, alas.)  What it is telling you is that the format of the `a` command includes a backslash, a newline, and then an argument denoted by *text*.  Everything in that column on the left, in other words.

As noted in question comments, `sed`s differ in how they handle malformed commands.  Spinellis `sed` yields an error, telling you that you have something other than the required backslash followed by newline:

```
% sed "/^\t\tkarmaServer.start/a\t\t\t\tflags: ['--no-sandbox']" /dev/null
sed: 1: "/^\t\tkarmaServer.start ...": extra characters after \ at the end of a command
%
```

Your particular choice of `sed` appears to be simply treating the rest of the line as the *text* argument.  But the first backslash there is still counting as the mandatory backslash that should follow `a`.  Therefore, what you end up with as the *text* argument is

```
t\t\t\tflags: ['--no-sandbox']
```

Notice the initial `t`, and one fewer tabs than you expected.

Comment: Right part of the manual.  Wrong actual answer.

Comment: @JdeBP is right... I needed to prepend `\ ` not only a `\`

Comment: Actually I need a few more backslashes on my machine: `sed "/^\t\tkarmaServer.start/a\\\\t\\t\\t\\tflags: ['--no-sandbox']" build/unit-test.coffee`

Comment: There you go.  That's what the manual is actually telling you.

Comment: @JdeBP Oh, wrong. Now mine works with one less... Got it, thanks!